# PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues) gives #VALUE

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel spreadsheet that exports to a temporary file, before performing a mail merge.
This is achived through a copy/paste as follows:

```
Dim current As Workbook
Set current = ActiveWorkbook

Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks.Add

current.Sheets("Input").UsedRange.Copy

' Only paste values, since posting formulas would give #REFERENCE errors
wb.Worksheets(1).name = "Input"
wb.Worksheets(1).Range("A1").PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
```

However, in one column i get #VALUE! in all the cells (Except for the header). These strings are longer than any other i am copying, with approximately 170-190 characters

---

## Edit

Digging into this problem i have stumbled upon something interesting. When poking around in another spreadsheet, while having the one im exporting open, causes the value to change.

The value of these cells are the location of the document, along with some details. I think that maybe this is causing the #VALUE! error - since the export opens a new workbook, with no location. If the formula was to be calculated at this point, i think it might give #VALUE! error.

Here is the formula:

```
=IF($A3<>"";CHAR(34) & SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(CELL("filnavn"); FIND("[";CELL("filnavn")) - 1) & "Images\" & INDIRECT("'" &VLOOKUP($G3;'Item Information'!$A$2:$C$249;3;FALSE) & "'!F2") & ".png"; "\"; "/") & CHAR(34); "")
```

Comment: Tried `wb.Worksheets(1).Range("A1").PasteSpecial(xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats)` ?

Comment: @PatricK Now i have; Same result...

Comment: Your finding explains the cause. The exported one does not have a named cell "filnavn". I would use a Long variable to store initial state of `.Calculation` and restore to it at the end since it has 3 possible states. Mark your answer as answer!

Comment: @PatricK Will do - but you can't accept your own answer before 48 hours have passed ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through debugging i found that it was indeed the formula that was causing problems, when adding a new workbook.

Setting `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual` before the code runs, and `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic` afterwards, solves this problems.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to copy values in VBA is (instead of copy & paste):

```
With current.Sheets("Input").UsedRange
    wb.Worksheets(1).Range("A1").Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count).Value=.Value
End With
```